# Mobile broadband not available in 20.04

Tags: mobile-broadband, 20.04

the "modem-manager" package is removed from 20.04 repo
I've tried *sudo snap install modem-manager*
but the snap package is not working

Answer (score 1):

i did a

```
sudo snap install modem-manager
```

and installation was successfull.

```
$ cat /etc/os-release 
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy- 
policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=focal
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal

$ uname -a
Linux xxx 5.4.0-26-generic #30-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 20 16:58:30 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

launching modem-manager ui did show the modem after reboot, enter sim pin and connection can be established

using lenovo t460, self installed huawei me906s-158 (name reported by modem-manager)